# Default variables in Bash

Tags: bash, perl, variable, for

The default variable for loops in Perl is `$_`. Is there any equivalent of this in Bash?

Comment: @Goro this is not a duplicate of that question, the topic there is `eval` for dynamic variable names.

Comment: @ RalfFriedl. Thank you for catching that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing in Bash. Perl is specific in the way that it's been created by a linguist, Larry Wall, and it has the natural language's smoothness built in on purpose. Bash in this respect is dumb.

But on a higher level, the pipelines are a sort of loops that operate on default objects. These are not represented by any symbol, and so they're implicitly default. (The pipelines are present in both Perl and Bash, in case you don't know.)

Answer (score 5):

No, in a `for` loop you have to use an explicit variable name.

```
$ help for
for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
```

The `NAME` is not optional.